# Can't produce any logs when run kafka consumer after setup cdc in sql server 2019 and register debezium sql server connector

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

Previously, I already setup CDC in SQL Server based on this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/enable-and-disable-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) and register Debezium SQL Server connector to Kafka connect based on this [link](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.1/connectors/sqlserver.html). I run Kafka consumer script and do some modification data(insert, update and delete) in SQL Server but Kafka consumer not display any JSON logs about modification data.

This is my configuration file `sqlserver-debezium.json`:

```
{
   "name":"sqlserver-debezium",
   "config":{
      "connector.class":"io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector",
      "database.user":"sa",
      "database.dbname":"cdc_sqlserver",
      "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers":"10.140.0.33:9092",
      "database.history.kafka.topic":"debezium_sqlserver",
      "database.server.name":"sqlserver-debezium",
      "database.port":"1433",
      "table.whitelist":"cdc_sqlserver_ipul.dbo.customers",
      "database.hostname":"10.140.15.214",
      "database.password":"test123",
      "name":"sqlserver-debezium",
      "include.query":"true",
      "snapshot.mode":"when_needed"
   }
}
```

I add the connector via the host machine as follows (just like the guide):

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" localhost:8083/connectors/ -d @sqlserver-debezium.json
```

Run script Kafka consumer:

```
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic sqlserver-connector --from-beginning
```

Will appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you check your Kafka Connect worker logs for errors and update your question to include them?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please double check the `table.whitelist` setting? It should be only `dbo.customers`.

Comment: I already change value table.whitelist become dbo.customers but still not display any JSON logs file in kafka consumer

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved. So i change value for variable `snapshot.mode` become `initial`, delete variabel include.query in sqlserver-debezium.json, retry register connector and do some modification(insert, update, delete) in sql server database then display json logs like this

```
{"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"int32","optional":false,"field":"id"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"first_name"
},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"last_name"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"email"}],"optional":true,"name":"btpns_sqlserver_ipul.dbo.customer
s.Value","field":"before"},{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"int32","optional":false,"field":"id"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"first_name"},{"type":
"string","optional":true,"field":"last_name"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"email"}],"optional":true,"name":"btpns_sqlserver_ipul.dbo.customers.Value","
field":"after"},{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"version"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"connector"},{"type":"stri
ng","optional":false,"field":"name"},{"type":"int64","optional":false,"field":"ts_ms"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"name":"io.debezium.data.Enum","version":1,"
parameters":{"allowed":"true,last,false"},"default":"false","field":"snapshot"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"db"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"f
ield":"schema"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"table"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"change_lsn"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"
commit_lsn"},{"type":"int64","optional":true,"field":"event_serial_no"}],"optional":false,"name":"io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.Source","field":"source"},{"type":
"string","optional":false,"field":"op"},{"type":"int64","optional":true,"field":"ts_ms"},{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"id"},
{"type":"int64","optional":false,"field":"total_order"},{"type":"int64","optional":false,"field":"data_collection_order"}],"optional":true,"field":"transaction"}],"
optional":false,"name":"btpns_sqlserver_ipul.dbo.customers.Envelope"},"payload":{"before":{"id":9,"first_name":"Andi","last_name":"Thompson","email":"kitt@acme.com"
},"after":{"id":9,"first_name":"Deni","last_name":"Thompson","email":"kitt@acme.com"},"source":{"version":"1.2.0-SNAPSHOT","connector":"sqlserver","name":"btpns-sql
server-ipul","ts_ms":1588740858363,"snapshot":"false","db":"btpns_cdc_sqlserver_ipul","schema":"dbo","table":"customers","change_lsn":"0000002d:00003da0:0002","comm
it_lsn":"0000002d:00003da0:0003","event_serial_no":2},"op":"u","ts_ms":1588740859225,"transaction":null}}
{"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"int32","optional":false,"field":"id"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"first_name"
},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"last_name"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"email"}],"optional":true,"name":"btpns_sqlserver_ipul.dbo.customer
s.Value","field":"before"},{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"int32","optional":false,"field":"id"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"first_name"},{"type":
"string","optional":true,"field":"last_name"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"email"}],"optional":true,"name":"btpns_sqlserver_ipul.dbo.customers.Value","
field":"after"},{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"version"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"connector"},{"type":"stri
ng","optional":false,"field":"name"},{"type":"int64","optional":false,"field":"ts_ms"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"name":"io.debezium.data.Enum","version":1,"
parameters":{"allowed":"true,last,false"},"default":"false","field":"snapshot"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"db"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"f
ield":"schema"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"table"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"change_lsn"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"
commit_lsn"},{"type":"int64","optional":true,"field":"event_serial_no"}],"optional":false,"name":"io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.Source","field":"source"},{"type":
"string","optional":false,"field":"op"},{"type":"int64","optional":true,"field":"ts_ms"},{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"id"},
{"type":"int64","optional":false,"field":"total_order"},{"type":"int64","optional":false,"field":"data_collection_order"}],"optional":true,"field":"transaction"}],"
optional":false,"name":"btpns_sqlserver_ipul.dbo.customers.Envelope"},"payload":{"before":{"id":9,"first_name":"Deni","last_name":"Thompson","email":"kitt@acme.com"
},"after":null,"source":{"version":"1.2.0-SNAPSHOT","connector":"sqlserver","name":"btpns-sqlserver-ipul","ts_ms":1588744428530,"snapshot":"false","db":"btpns_cdc_s
qlserver_ipul","schema":"dbo","table":"customers","change_lsn":"0000002d:00005400:0002","commit_lsn":"0000002d:00005400:0005","event_serial_no":1},"op":"d","ts_ms":
1588744430725,"transaction":null}}
```